# bootstrap-select is not showing dropdown after click

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-select

https://codepen.io/yudizkkw/pen/GRKYdjz

```
<select class="selectpicker">
    <option>Mustard</option>
    <option>Ketchup</option>
    <option>Relish</option>
  </select>
```

For the above select component, it contains 3 elements. But after click, nothing shows up.

Comment: For most libraries, it's a good idea to read [Getting started](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/) before you use them. Especially when they don't seem to work out of the box. In your case, the problem seems to be you don't have a valid Bootstrap setup. You're trying to combine the CSS from v4.0.0 with bits and pieces from v3.4.x. Decide which version of Bootstrap you're going to use and then follow the quick start guide of bootstrap select. If you do all of that and it still doesn't work, update your question.

Answer (score 1):

You should go through the [Getting started with Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/) and [Quick Start Guide](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/)

As per the getting started guide,

> Bootstrap-select requires jQuery v1.9.1+, Bootstrap’s dropdown.js component, and Bootstrap's CSS. If you're not already using Bootstrap in your project, a precompiled version of the Bootstrap v3.3.7 minimum requirements can be downloaded here. If using bootstrap-select with Bootstrap v4+, you'll also need Popper.js. For all of Bootstrap v4's requirements, see Getting started. A precompiled version of the requirements will be made available in an upcoming release of bootstrap-select.

https://codepen.io/yudizkkw/pen/GRKYdjz?editors=1010

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<!-- (Optional) Latest compiled and minified JavaScript translation files -->
  
</head>
<body>
  <select class="selectpicker">
    <option>Mustard</option>
    <option>Ketchup</option>
    <option>Relish</option>
  </select> 
</body>
</html>
```